# univariate features selection with a minimum score

Tags: python, scikit-learn

This is a partial followup of: [passing an extra argument to GenericUnivariateSelect without scope tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46559634/passing-an-extra-argument-to-genericunivariateselect-without-scope-tricks/46580194?noredirect=1#comment80118553_46580194)

I need to perform univariate feature selection in sklearn with a custom score, therefore I am using GenericUnivariateSelect.
However, as in documentation,

modes for selectors : {‘percentile’, ‘k_best’,           ‘fpr’, ‘fdr’, ‘fwe’}

In my case, I needed to select features where the score was above a certain value, so I have implemented:

```
 class SelectMinScore(_BaseFilter):
     # Sklearn documentation: modes for selectors : {‘percentile’, ‘k_best’,      ‘fpr’, ‘fdr’, ‘fwe’}
def __init__(self, score_func=f_classif, minScore=0.7):
    super(SelectMinScore, self).__init__(score_func)
    self.minScore = minScore
    self.score_func=score_func
def _check_params(self, X, y):
    if not (self.minScore == "all" or 0 <= self.minScore <= 1):
        raise ValueError("minScore should be >=0, <= 1; got %r."
                         "Use minScore='inf' to return all features."
                         % self.minScore)

def _get_support_mask(self):
    check_is_fitted(self, 'scores_')

    if self.minScore == 'all':
        return np.ones(self.scores_.shape, dtype=bool)
    else:
        scores = _clean_nans(self.scores_)
        mask = np.zeros(scores.shape, dtype=bool)
        -------------------------------------
        # Custom part
        # only score above the min
        mask=scores>self.minScore
        if not np.any(mask):
            mask[np.argmax(scores)]=True
        return mask
```

which seems legit to me. When I try to use it:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection.univariate_selection import _clean_nans
from sklearn.feature_selection.univariate_selection import f_classif                        
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from  sklearn.feature_selection import GenericUnivariateSelect
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer 
from sklearn.feature_selection.univariate_selection import _BaseFilter
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline 

def Custom_Score(X,Y,extradata):
  return 1
class myClass:
    def my_method():
     _extradata=np.random.rand(500,1)

     my_scorer = make_scorer(Custom_Score,extradata=_extradata)
     custom_filter=GenericUnivariateSelect(my_scorer,mode='MinScore',param=0.7)   
     custom_filter._selection_modes.update({'MinScore': SelectMinScore})
     MyProcessingPipeline=Pipeline(steps=[('filter_step', custom_filter)])
     # finally test it 
     X=pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(500,3))
     y=pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(500,1))
     MyProcessingPipeline.fit(X,y)
     MyProcessingPipeline.transform(X,y)
     Xt=MyProcessingPipeline.transform(X)
```

My expectation would be to get Xt identical to X

Is this feasible?

Instead, I get the following:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-31-f493745d7e1b>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/Users/\_______\/Desktop/pd-sk-integration.py', wdir='C:/Users/\_______\/Desktop')
File "C:\Users\\_______\\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)
File "C:\Users\\_______\\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 87, in execfile
exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
File "C:/Users/\_______/Desktop/pd-sk-integration.py", line 59, in <module>
MyProcessingPipeline.fit(X,y)
File "C:\Users\\_______\\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 270, in fit
self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params)
File "C:\Users\_______\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\univariate_selection.py", line 330, in fit
score_func_ret = self.score_func(X, y)
TypeError: __call__() takes at least 4 arguments (3 given)
```

---

EDIT:

If I pass the score function directly
 `custom_filter=GenericUnivariateSelect(Custom_Score,mode='MinScore',param=0.7)`

I get:

```
File "C:\Users\\_____\\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 87, in execfile
exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
File "C:/Users/\_____\/Desktop/pd-sk-integration.py", line 59, in <module>
MyProcessingPipeline.fit(X,y)
File "C:\Users\\_____\\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 270, in fit
self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params)
File "C:\Users\_____\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\univariate_selection.py", line 330, in fit
score_func_ret = self.score_func(X, y)
TypeError: Custom_Score() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Comment: This error is because you have not passed any `y`. All [univatiate selection methods](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html#univariate-feature-selection) IMO require the target variable y to be present.

Comment: that's correct. But even after adding y, it still does not work for me. I am updating the traceback

Comment: I am still convinced is a argument passing issues between the .fit() and .score_func() but it is this the desired behavior

Comment: The assumption in your previous question is wrong. You cannot use `make_scorer` like that. The output of make_scorer is a function with `signature (estimator, X, y)` which does not match what you want. This is the source of error.

Comment: so what is the right way to use a score function which needs to receive additional inputs other than X, y ?

Comment: That depends on when you want to give the additional input. Do you have the extra data ready before initializing the selector as in the current case, where you pass it to `make_scorer` ? If yes, dont wrap the score function in `make_scorer`, pass it as it is. Handle the extra_data inside the score function.

Comment: I have the extra data before initializing the scores

Comment: However, if I pass it directly, I get   
  File "C:\Users\________\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\univariate_selection.py", line 330, in fit
    score_func_ret = self.score_func(X, y)

TypeError: Custom_Score() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Comment: Remove the `extradata` from the signature of the custom function, use it directly inside for your calculations

Comment: here is the real problem: the whole thing is used within a class, where the `extradata` are available. If I define `Custom_Score` outside the class, then it does not see `extradata`

Comment: I will probably create a new question out of this